# Get users current location from Facebook messenger Chatbot api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I am working on fb messenger bot and I want to access user's current location without them sending it as an attachment.I tried to get user's current location from fb graph API but it seems like to return the user's location from their profile. I need something like real time geo coordinates.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You can't. The user has to send it

Answer (score 5):

The only way to get the location is when the user sends it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies

More information: [How to send location from Facebook messenger platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017382/how-to-send-location-from-facebook-messenger-platform)

Comment: Unfortunately you don't have access to Javascript in the FB Bot API

Comment: then it´s not possible at all in an automatic way (without user interaction)

Comment: Correct. There is no Javascript access and you can't get users IP address and the API won't give you the location.

Comment: So does mean everytime you want a location you need to ask for it via the quick reply, or does a permission get set that allows it for a period of time?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure there is no **automatic** geo-location support in the FB messenger API but:

1. On mobile you can have them submit their location using the location icon, this works pretty well (gives you their lat and long)
2. On both desktop and mobile you can ask them to input their location, then use that information to get their coordinates