# What would be the right way to ask the person to enter a city inside a bot?

Tags: bots, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I have a situation where I need to ask the city from the user inside a Messenger bot. The location pin works only on mobiles and hence the problem. A city like 'Springfield' has 41 results whereas some cities only have a few.

Currently, I am using the generic template as shown below to show the list of cities but this is obviously not the correct way. The generic template has a limit of 10 items it seems as per the tests I ran and sending quick replies asking "Is A your city | Yes | No" , "Is B your city | Yes | No" is pretty bad...
[image]

Any suggestions for this? Should I ask the country name if I have more than 1 result for the city names?

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for zip code. I understand this will significantly reduce the number of possible cities. In response, you can send a [message specifying a location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017382/how-to-send-location-from-facebook-messenger-platform/38246806#38246806). And to ask whether you have correctly guessed the place

For searching place by zip code you can use [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

Comment: thanks for the input, there is one issue however :) you cannot use Google maps geocoding API without displaying a google map wherever you are using geocoding, read their terms of service Check 10.4d here https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_4

Comment: @PirateApp But I display map. More precisely, I show something similar to your screenshot, just with a map (send location by the bot).