# display map in facebook messenger bot

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger

I need to show map in facebook messenger bot. According to documentation following code should work but I only see message and place icon. Has anyone faced similar issue.

```
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: userId
    },
    message: {
      text: msg,
      metadata: "DEVELOPER_DEFINED_METADATA",
      quick_replies: [
        {
          "content_type": "location"
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  callSendAPI(messageData);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send location from Facebook messenger platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017382/how-to-send-location-from-facebook-messenger-platform)

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that code works but only from messenger app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use this functionality without a problem on the IOS messenger app.  The 'location' feature allows the user to send a their location to the bot.  By default, it showed a map with 'Your Location' and 'Tap to view on map'.

I tried from the desktop and it gave an error indicating that locations are only usable in the app.

The bot is running at [DMS Software Bot.](https://m.me/dynamicmemorysolutions)  Type 'quick reply' and hit location.

The source is at [FB-Robot](https://github.com/matthewericfisher/fb-robot) on github.